# The job graph is too large. Dataflow Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataflow

"The job graph is too large. Please try again with a smaller job graph. or split your job into two or more smaller jobs"

I have successfully set a path to the data file locally. (Data size is not small.)

```python
contents = data_ingestion.read_json(input_path)

class preProcessing(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        if element["WORKER"] is None : 
             element["WORKER"]=None

class DataIngestion:
    def __init__(self, schema_path):
        with open(schema_path) as f:
            data = f.read()
            self.schema_str = '{"fields" : ' + data + '}'

    def read_json(self, data_path):
        with open(data_path,'r', encoding="cp949") as f:
            contents = json.load(f)
            return contents

go = (p
    | "Start Create Data" >> beam.Create(contents)
    | "String To BigQuery Row" >> beam.ParDo(preProcessing())
 
 go | "Write" >> beam.io.Write(
                    beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                    schema=parse_table_schema_from_json(data_ingestion.schema_str),
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

I understand that there is a lot of data processing in one Job and the issue occurs.
I've checked all the other similar Q&A, but there's no suitable solution, so I'm replying to the question.
What should I do to solve the problem?
Thank you :3

Comment: Where data is parked, which you are reading in Data Pipeline, is it on GCS ? Are you are running it in Dataflow or Local ?

Comment: @VibhorGupta, Yes It is stored in GCS. runner is DataflowRunner.

Comment: How much data are you talking about when you say "data size is not small"?